# Insert into one table then update another

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Hi People I'm looking to insert into one table then pass other information to update another.

I'm currently using an ajax command to do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "syncdata.php",
    data: {depot: json, techname: techsname}})
    .done(function(data){
                //do something
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert("Something went wrong.<br>ER: SY01");
    });
```

My data - depot is an object that does not contain the techname.
The depot information gets stored within a table called "depotreport".
The techname includes just the usersID number which i wish to store within another table called jobs.

**syncdata.php**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
depotreport (JobID, SiteID, VisitDate, AirPress, LELMeth, VolMeth, PPMMeth, LELProp, VolProp, VisitType, ConditionPipes, SignOp, SignSpar, SignReg, SignCylin, CheckWorking, CheckFilter, CheckoRing, CheckGNozzle, CheckRBlock, CheckSAlign, CheckMSwitch, CheckLED, RepFilter, RepBlock, CheckSolenoid, CheckSoRing, CheckHW, CheckDValue, CheckPCB, RepDisk, CheckDisk, CheckDT40, Working, GascoNo, TestDepot, DepotSat, TestGMI, GMISat, DepotDisk, PrintDepot, PrintGMI, TestInst, AuditInst, PPMInst, TestReason, AuditReason, PPMReason, AuditComplete) 
VALUES 
('$ID[$i]', '$SiteID[$i]', '$visitDate[$i]', '$numAirP[$i]', '$numLelM[$i]', '$numAVolM[$i]', '$numPpmM[$i]', '$numLelP[$i]', '$numVolP[$i]', 'this', '$flpHoses[$i]', '$flpOperating[$i]', '$flpSpares[$i]', '$flpRegs[$i]', '$flpCylC[$i]', '$flpWorking[$i]', '$flpFcleaned[$i]', '$flpOring[$i]', '$flpCgas[$i]', '$flpRblock[$i]', '$flpSensor[$i]', '$flpMicroswitch[$i]', '$flpLed[$i]', '$flpFchanged[$i]', '$flpBrenew[$i]', '$flpSvalves[$i]', '$flpSoRings[$i]', '$flpHWtest[$i]', '$flpTestD[$i]', '$flpPCB[$i]', '$flpDhead[$i]', '$flpDchanged[$i]', '$flpDT40[$i]', '$flpWorkingDe[$i]', '$numGasCo[$i]', '$datetDepot[$i]', '$flpDSatisfactory[$i]', '$datetGmi[$i]', '$flpGSatisfactory[$i]', '$dateDdisk[$i]', '$flpPrintoutD[$i]', '$flpPrintoutG[$i]', '$numTestIns[$i]', '$numAuditIns[$i]', '$numPpmIns[$i]', '$flpTCall[$i]', '$flpACall[$i]', '$flpPCall[$i]', '$dateAuditC[$i]');

UPDATE
jobs (CompletedBy)
SET
('$tech')
WHERE JobID = '$ID[$i]'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} 
else{
  $synctotal++;
}
```

I've had a look around and found out that if i use a semicolon between my insert and my update it should work, this is not the case. I have also looked a triggers but i cannot do it that way because my depotreport does not contain anything to do with my techname.

Could someone please enlighten me to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think what you need is `mysqli::multi_query`.  Check out [this PHP documentation file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) about that method.

Comment: Can you show it on context for me?

Comment: mysqli::multi_query is disabled on the server im using to stop injection. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, you could look into transactions.  Other than that you might be stuck crafting multiples statements and multipe calls to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Create a trigger in MySQL (yes, it has triggers nowadays).